# How to output stream from camera(recording in RTSP) via FFmpeg (Kokorin Jaffree)

Tags: java, spring, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, rtsp

I'm trying to reach watching live hls stream in browser based on rtsp-camera stream from java-client using Jafree library(https://github.com/kokorin/Jaffree).

But I could not execute the command due to a lack of FFmpeg rights(FFmpeg is installed in /usr/bin/ffmpeg)
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OFR8.png)

And I also tried to execute this command from runtime:

```
sudo ffmpeg -fflags nobuffer  -rtsp_transport tcp  -i rtsp://my_url  -vsync 0  -copyts  -vcodec copy  -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov  -an  -hls_flags delete_segments+append_list  -f segment  -segment_list_flags live  -segment_time 1  -segment_list_size 3  -segment_format mpegts  -segment_list /temp/stream/index.m3u8  -segment_list_type m3u8  -segment_list_entry_prefix /stream/  /temp/stream/%d.ts
```

I can execute it in the console and everything is ok, but on the browser I get CORS trying to access it.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUltG.png)

Could you please share a way to achieve stream in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put ffmpeg and ffprobe to project's root folder.
Then you can use FFmpeg class without any rules or paths.
Just like this:

```
    public void doSmth() {
       FFmpeg.atPath()
        .addInput(UrlInput.fromUrl(""))
        .addOutput(
            UrlOutput.toUrl("your MediaServer's url")
        ).execute();
    }
```